# Restricting information to metadata sections in GeoNetwork?

Tags: geonetwork

As said in [Linking website, web services, … using URL](https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/3.6.x/en/user-guide/associating-resources/linking-online-resources.html) when having information about the database or file on the local network, it may be relevant to hide those informations for public users. But [this section](https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/3.6.x/en/user-guide/publishing/restricting-information-to-metadata-sections.html#restricting-information-to-metadata-sections) is empty. Where can I find related information?